# after upgrade to 4.6.26 getting PHP Fatal error when starting a new mailing

Tags: mailing

I just upgraded from 4.6.23 to 4.6.26.  I'm on wordpress. Everything else seems to work fine. When I start a new mailing I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing:
>   :getTemplateTypes() in
>   ...wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Info.php on line
>   168, referer: ...

I see that getTemplateTypes is new for 4.6.26.  I see in civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php that the function is defined there.

I've commented out the reference to getTemplateTypes in civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Info.php and that allows me to start a new mailing, but now I'm getting this PHP warning:

> PHP Warning:  call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid c allback, class 'CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing' does not have a method
>   'getTemplateTypeNames' in
>   .../civicrm/CRM/Core/PseudoConstant.php on line 277, ...

Comment: Since you see the method there but it doesn't find it, maybe you have a caching issue.   You might try doing the same thing from a private or incognito browswer session and see if that works.  It could be on the civi side so you could try to clear all of civi's caches.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions and it doesn't seem to be a caching problem.

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? I've just had the same thing updating from 4.6.24 to 4.6.28 - starting a new mailing throws a HTTP Error 500 and creates the 'Call to undefined method CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing: :getTemplateTypes()' error in the server log.

Comment: No. Not resolved.  As I stated in the last paragraph, after commenting out the reference to getTemplateTypes...  I can start and complete mailings.

Comment: Rich Smith, just alerting you to the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing class is overriden somewhere. This could be due to a civicrm extension like mailjet that overrides Mailing.php

Please check which extension is overriding it and either disable that extension or update Mailing.php in it.

Let me know if it works!

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!  I have a sendgrid extension that must be doing what you say.  I'll check for an update to that extension.